# Script runs fine in the browser console, but not online

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom

I'm working with a Wordpress website, where I'm building a navigation bar. One of the features I'd like to add is where if you're on a certain page, the option in the navigation bar will be bold to represent that is the section of the site you're visiting.

I'm attempting to achieve this using JavaScript, as I have no working knowledge of PHP:

```
var current_page = document.URL;
var current_option_id="";
if(current_page==="some-url"){
  current_option_id="menu-item-34";
}
document.getElementById(current_option_id).getElementsByTagName("A")[0].style.fontWeight="bold";
```

Basically, my code figures out which page we're on, and will assign the right menu option's id to the `current_option` variable. Then, the script will attempt to select the 
proper menu option, select the link inside that menu option, and change its style.

The problem with this script is that it simply won't work, generating an error where it cannot select the HTML element; `document.getElementById(current_option);` returns null. **However**, when I do this in the console, it works fine, and the style is changed properly. Why is this? I know that the `current_option` variable has the correct value, but the script fails when it tries to select the element to change.

Any suggestions and help are greatly appreciated. If you know how to do this in PHP with something that will integrate nicely with Wordpress, please do share (and explain how your code works!). If I broke any StackOverflow rule, my apologies.

Comment: Is DOM ready when your code starts to run?

Comment: That was the issue, as orzechowskid pointed out. Thanks a lot for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to say without seeing your code, but is there a chance that your script is being executed before your entire page is loaded (or, more specifically, before the element with id `#menu-item-34` has been added to the DOM)?

Try wrapping your script inside a function, and then setting that function as your page's onload handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    /* code goes here */
};
```

Comment: That was the issue! Such a silly mistake, I guess I kinda assumed the DOM was prepared super-fast, and then the script was run. Regardless, I appreciate the help from everyone who's posted or commented.